# Number of ways of making a proper fraction.

Tags: combinatorics, programming

Given n relative prime integers find the number of ways to make a proper fraction (i.e. numerator < denominator).

The answer is 2^(n-1) as for every integer we have two options either it goes in numerator or in denominator so answer is (total combinations/2).

I cannot understand,why the above statement holds?That is, how can we prove the statement mathematically.

Comment: I'm thinking like this: You have an array of numbers, let's say
$$
\{2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 21 \}
$$
In how many ways can you make a fraction out of these so that the numerator is smaller than the denominator? This is equal to choosing two numbers out of the list. Then you just have to divide by two to make sure count out the cases where the numerator is larger than the denominator. Isn't this equivalent to the problem? For example I could choose $5$ and $17$. There's only one way to make such a fraction out of these two.

Comment: Ah but can you choose more than one number? Is there a limit on how many of them you can choose?

Comment: Yes you can choose more than one number.

Comment: So you could make, for example,
$$
\frac{2 \cdot 5}{ 7 \cdot 17 \cdot 19} = 2^1 \cdot 5^1 \cdot 7^{-1} \cdot 17^{-1} \cdot 19^{-1}
$$

Comment: Yes also 2.3.5/7.11.13.17.19.21 is valid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider *all* fractions you could make. There are $2^n$ of these, like you mentioned above. Half of these are proper. This is so since every fraction consisting of relative primes will either be proper or improper (i.e. none of them equals exactly 1) and to each improper fraction $\frac{p}{q}$ we have the corresponding proper fraction $\frac{q}{p}$.